# List System Properties in a textarea using javax.swing/javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8, jtextarea

**how can I display all System Properties in a javafx or swing Textarea;
in a format like 
"key1"=value1
"key2"=value2**
I tried `*textarea.setText(System.getProperties().toString()),*`
but that just listed it like this;

```
{javafx.version=8.0.72, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin, java.vm.version=25.77-b03, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.o......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version of this using Java 8 features would look like

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

// or, in Swing, JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

textArea.setText( System.getProperties().entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> String.format("\"%s\" = %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

If you don't need quotes around the keys, you can replace the map step with the simpler

```
    .map(Object::toString)
```

Comment: That is JavaFX code... Replace the first line with the commented-out line if you want Swing.

Comment: Oh sorry, just noticed that its a Textarea in Javafx and not a jtextarea xD

Comment: Both work, of course... because all that's really happening is converting a list of properties to a big string with embedded new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this if you want each key/value on a separate line:

```
String out = System.getProperties().toString.replaceAll(", ", "\n");
textarea.setText(out);
```

I am not positive if the textArea uses the "\n" for line separation, but it will have a separator.

If you want the key to be in quotes, then use the Enumeration on the properties.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    Enumeration<?> e = props.propertyNames();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String)e.nextElement();
        String val = props.getProperty(key);
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append("\""); sb.append(key); sb.append("\"="); sb.append(val);
    }

    textarea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your code this (I tried to shorten it as much as I could):

```
String text = "";
for(String sp : System.getProperties().toString().substring(1, System.getProperties().toString().length() - 2).split(","))text += "\n" + "\"" + sp.split("=")[0].trim() + "\"=" + sp.split("=")[0].trim();
text = text.replaceFirst("\n", "");
textarea.setText(text);
```